# Android Studio AVD emulator cannot find multiple laptop cameras

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I'm very new to Android Studio, but I am working on an app that needs to use the camera (specifically android.hardware.camera2) and even just launching the regular camera app on a virtual device results in the error "Could not open the camera" and the app crashing.

I've tried using the simulated camera and that works fine, but as soon as I update either to Webcam0 it will not open.

The computer is a Surface Pro 4, so it has a front and rear facing camera, but this is not specified on the menu?

The virtual device I'm currently using is a Pixel 3 XL (although I've tried all of them) with Android 9.+ x86 on API 29, running with Multi-Core CPU enabled and 1536 MB of RAM.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!